# Calculating flux jacobian using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I want to obtain the analytical expression of the flux Jacobian of an advection equation in a porous media, which is useful when doing computational fluid dynamics. I thought that I could do that easily in Sympy but I am stuck somewhere.

Here are my equations:

[image]

with phi beeing the porosity, C the concentration of an element and v the fluid velocity.

The flux jacobian in my case is simply:

[image]

I can compute v using Darcy's law:

[image]

with k the permeability, nf the fluid viscosity and Pf the fluid pressure.

The permeability depends on phi with this very simple relationship:

[image]

by doing this very simple change of variable, I can simplify my problem:

[image]

[image]

That is what I've tried to solve in Sympy that way:

```
from sympy import * 

# Create symbols
k0, phi, n, Pn, Pc, Ps, C = symbols('k0 phi n P_{i+1} P_{i} P_{i-1} C')
C_tild = phi * C
dx = Symbol(r"\Delta x")
nf = Symbol(r"\mu_f")

# Darcy's law while using finite differences for the Gradient operator in the pressure term
qf = (k0 * phi**n / nf) * (((Pn + Pc)/2 - (Ps + Pc)/2) / dx)
vf = qf / phi

flux = vf * C_tild
display(flux)
derivative = diff(flux, C_tild)
```

This return an error because I am trying to do a derivative with two variables (phi and C) at the same time.
What am I doing wrong here? How can I make Sympy understand my change of variable? Or can I rewrite my Jacobian with a simpler expression?

EDIT

The error is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/h6/3p69g_d146x78r6b75_h_td40000gp/T/ipykernel_64334/485359947.py in <module>
     11 flux = vf * C_tild
     12 display(flux)
---> 13 derivative = diff(flux, C_tild)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Two-phase_flow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py in diff(f, *symbols, **kwargs)
   2497     """
   2498     if hasattr(f, 'diff'):
-> 2499         return f.diff(*symbols, **kwargs)
   2500     kwargs.setdefault('evaluate', True)
   2501     return _derivative_dispatch(f, *symbols, **kwargs)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Two-phase_flow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py in diff(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
   3526     def diff(self, *symbols, **assumptions):
   3527         assumptions.setdefault("evaluate", True)
-> 3528         return _derivative_dispatch(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
   3529 
   3530     ###########################################################################

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Two-phase_flow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py in _derivative_dispatch(expr, *variables, **kwargs)
   1921         from sympy.tensor.array.array_derivatives import ArrayDerivative
   1922         return ArrayDerivative(expr, *variables, **kwargs)
-> 1923     return Derivative(expr, *variables, **kwargs)
   1924 
   1925 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Two-phase_flow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py in __new__(cls, expr, *variables, **kwargs)
   1346             if not v._diff_wrt:
   1347                 __ = ''  # filler to make error message neater
-> 1348                 raise ValueError(filldedent('''
   1349                     Can't calculate derivative wrt %s.%s''' % (v,
   1350                     __)))

ValueError: 
Can't calculate derivative wrt C*phi.
```

Comment: SO is better for debugging code, in this case `sympy`, not so much the math and equations behind it.  So seeing things like `flux`, and the actual error that sympy returns is more important than the images.

Comment: What exactly is the derivative of `x*y**n` wrt `x*y`? How do you expect sympy to understand what that is supposed to mean? If either is supposed to be a constant then you can just pull that out of the denominator and differentiate wrt the other.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I actually don't really know, that's why I am using sympy aha. n is a constant in that case. But maybe I have to consider y**n constant in this case, otherwise I am stuck.

Comment: @hpaulj alright, that explains why I can't write equations with Latex. I've edited my post with the error

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here's your code in a `isympy` session

```
In [7]: k0, phi, n, Pn, Pc, Ps, C = symbols('k0 phi n P_{i+1} P_{i} P_{i-1} C')
   ...: C_tild = phi * C
   ...: dx = Symbol(r"\Delta x")
   ...: nf = Symbol(r"\mu_f")
   ...: 
   ...: # Darcy's law while using finite differences for the Gradient operator i
   ...: n the pressure term
   ...: qf = (k0 * phi**n / nf) * (((Pn + Pc)/2 - (Ps + Pc)/2) / dx)
   ...: vf = qf / phi
   ...: 
   ...: flux = vf * C_tild

In [8]: flux
Out[8]: 
      n ⎛P_{i+1}   P_{i-1}⎞
C⋅k₀⋅φ ⋅⎜─────── - ───────⎟
        ⎝   2         2   ⎠
───────────────────────────
       \Delta x⋅\mu_f      

In [9]: C_tild
Out[9]: C⋅φ
```

Since `C` is a simple multiplier, I don't think it adds anything to the calculation.  Just use `flux` without the `C`, to get:

```
In [18]: diff(vf*phi, phi)
Out[18]: 
      n ⎛P_{i+1}   P_{i-1}⎞
k₀⋅n⋅φ ⋅⎜─────── - ───────⎟
        ⎝   2         2   ⎠
───────────────────────────
      \Delta x⋅\mu_f⋅φ
```

Comment: Thx, I will present it this way the next time I am writing a post with SymPy. So I guess the problem here is the ^n..

Comment: What does `C` represent?  Does it's value make any difference, either the `flux` or the derivative?  Without it, the `diff` works.  Note that mostly this basically a `Const * phi^n` calculation, with a straight forward derivative in `phi`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the derivative is quite straightforward without C. 
C is the concentration of the element I am advecting in my fluid. It doesn't have any relation with the fluid velocity but it is quite important for the flux. So it is not constant in space and in time.